# how i can test my flutter custom statefulwidget parameter change

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

i have a custom widget named "**Counter**" and i can pass some parameters in it, like initiaValue, onChange callback etc.

now i write a test case to test the "**Counter**" widget when the initiavalue change, here is my test case code:

```dart
  testWidgets('Counter value option can set every number and can change everytime', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

    int counterInitVal = 10;
    await tester.pumpWidget(
      MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Counter(
            customTextController: controller,
            value: counterInitVal,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

    expect(controller.text, equals("10"));

    counterInitVal = 20;
    await tester.pumpAndSettle(Duration(milliseconds: 600));

    expect(controller.text, equals("20"));
  });
```

the first expect is pass and the second is failed, so how i can test it ?

Answer (score 0):

The `int` type is not the referencing type. So the value doesn't affect the value of the `Counter`. And the `Counter` widget doesn't rerender when just changing a value.

In this case, using a state management tool like the Provider is the best choice.

Or using your function in the `Counter` widget for testing.